# java.sql.SQLException no suitable driver found but can connect perfectly in Netbeans

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception

I have been Googling this for the last 3 hours and I can not believe how little information there is on it. I have used the ODBC drivers to connect in C++ applications, PDO in PHP etc and I thought connecting in Java would be easy.

I get this exception `java.sql.SQLException no suitable driver found.` when I try

```
// Connect to the database
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name", "root", "");
    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(NULL, ex);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

I am using Netbeans and in the Services tab I can connect to the database perfectly and it says it is using the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` driver so it must be on the computer so it is really annoying me now.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Is the driver in your classpath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure the the MySQL JDBC Driver is loaded into the classpath prior to attempting to connect to the database

`DriverManager` will automatically load the driver class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`.

Comment: You also need to make sure that the driver is added to your classpath at compile time.

Comment: There should be no need to use `Class.forName` these days. `DriverManager` should take care of it, if the class is on the classpath properly.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In my environment variables in the PATH I have "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext" where my "mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin" but I still get the same exception.

Comment: @David check that the JAR has not been corrupted. As a side note I would move the JAR file into the classpath of the application itself rather than having it in the JRE extension lib directory

Comment: Ok I will try that. One thing though, when I move this jar file by itself to a new location how does it then know where all the other files that came with it are? The files in the com.mysql.jdbc folder?

Comment: @David After a quick test, no need to even load the JDBC class, just ensure that the JAR is on the classpath and it will work

Answer (score 1):

You are not including the driver, try that

```
// Connect to the database
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schema_name", "root", "");
    }
   catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Driver not found\n"+ ex);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    catch(SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  ex);
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

This is what, called `Loading Class at Runtime`.